# Yii framework RBAC model, trying to understand

Tags: php, yii, rbac

In accessRules, anyway I add all actions allowed for certain role, like below

```
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array(‘create’,'view’),
        'roles'=>array('role1'),
```

Why should I create operations? What is the benefit of creating separate operations like below? I know I can use checkAccess method if I create operations, but in accessRules I list all actions that certain role is allowed to perform so I don’t have to add operations to that role right ?

```
_authManager->createOperation("createPost ", "create a new post");
_authManager->createOperation("readPost ", "read post");
$role = $this->_authManager->createRole("role1");
$role->addChild("createPost");
$role->addChild("readPost");
```

I checked, If I allow role1 actions of delete and admin, it will allow be to perform those actions even though I didn’t add that operation to role1.

```
    array('allow',
        'actions'=>array(‘admin’,'delete’),
        'roles'=>array('role1'),
```

So, what is the benefit of adding operations to role when it doesn’t enforce restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to UserIdentity setRole method

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==md5($this->password))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->id=$record->id;
            $this->setState('roles', $record->roles);            
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Also WebUser component

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
    /**
     * Overrides a Yii method that is used for roles in controllers (accessRules).
     *
     * @param string $operation Name of the operation required (here, a role).
     * @param mixed $params (opt) Parameters for this operation, usually the object to access.
     * @return bool Permission granted?
     */
    public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            // Not identified => no rights
            return false;
        }
        $role = $this->getState("roles");
        if ($role === 'admin') {
            return true; // admin role has access to everything
        }
        // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
        return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

Check [full description there](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac)